# Is possible to get event handler by element in site written in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

How to obtain code of event handler in Google Chrome Console?

For a site written in VannilaJS I can do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
getEventListeners(el);
```

For a site written in jQuery I can do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
$._data(el, 'events');
```

But for a site written in React I am not able to get the exact code to execute once the event occurs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access event listeners in the console purely for debugging purposes, I should use the inspector to find the DOM element with the event attached to it, and beside that should be a little 'event' label. Click on that to see a list of events. This is far easier than writing commands in the console every time. If you don't fancy that, `document.getElementById('test')` will still work with React; just add the id attribute as you would if you were writing regular HTML.

If you wish to access the events on a DOM element for some other reason, the way to access DOM elements in React is using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). You can then call `getEventListeners` or whatever else you want to do and pass in the ref which will be the DOM element. Be careful not to overuse refs though; there is a time and a place for them, as the linked page explains.